# Error : len() of unsized object - Wilconox signed-rank test

Tags: pandas, statistics, comparison, data-science

I am running Wilconox signed-rank test on the dataset which looks like :

```
df = {'Year': ['2019','2018','2017', ....], 'Name':{jon, tim, luca,...}, 'SelfPromotion': [1,0,1,...]}
```

the script is as follows:

```
import pandas
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

data1 = df['SelfPromotion']=1
data2 = df['SelfPromotion']=0
print(mannwhitneyu(data1, data2))
```

this gives me the following error:

**TypeError:** len() of unsized object

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-e49d9838e5ac> in <module>
      3 data1 = data['SelfPromotion']=1
      4 data2 = data['SelfPromotion']=0
----> 5 print(mannwhitneyu(data11, data22))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/shityaar/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in mannwhitneyu(x, y, use_continuity, alternative)
   6391     x = np.asarray(x)
   6392     y = np.asarray(y)
-> 6393     n1 = len(x)
   6394     n2 = len(y)
   6395     ranked = rankdata(np.concatenate((x, y)))

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I have tried every possible solution for this error by looking at similar questions but unfortunately, no solution could get it to work. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mannwhitneyu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) expects `array` like parameters and you are passing integers as args, hence the failure.

Do something like this:

```
In [26]: data1 = df['SelfPromotion'] == 1                                                                                                                                                                     
In [28]: data2 = df['SelfPromotion'] == 0

In [31]: mannwhitneyu(data1, data2)                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[31]: MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3.0, pvalue=0.30962837708843105)
```

Comment: hi, I am getting the same error and I tried the solution that you provided but sadly it didn't work. please have a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215139/how-to-fix-mann-whitney-u-for-error-len-of-unsized-object-pyspark)